# Help me with my hand Brakes

Tags: honda, civic, handbrake

I have a 2007 Honda Civic DX sedan. Recently my hand brakes stop staying up. Mechanic said the cables are good but I need some sort of clip or spring but he isn't sure because he is unfamiliar with this vehicle. Can someone help?

Comment: have you physically inspected anything.  checked the spring, checked the cable.  anything like that?

Comment: A friend of mine took of the outer arm which is broken nut we didn't see a spring is their supposed to be one?@DucatiKiller

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your parking brake has a return spring.  You should be able to goto a local auto parts store to get that and the arm replaced.

I also recommend you find another mechanic as most of this information is available on the Internet.

Hope this helpful.

[image]